# Python unable to find file in folder tree

Tags: python, ruby

I'm getting an error when I try to load one of the configuration files. Here is the folder structure:

1. script.rb
2. root_folder

   - command_line_interface.py
   - extras

     - utils.py
     - AZ

       - config1.txt
       - config2.txt
     - BZ

       - config1.txt
       - config2.txt

The query folows: **script.rb > command_line_interface.py > utils.py > config2.txt**

In *script.rb*:

```
IO.popen("./root_folder/command_line_interface.py -arg1 5")
```

In *command_line_interface.py*:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test')
    parser.add_argument('-arg1', '--arg1', action='store', type=int, help='Test', dest='arg1')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.arg1:
        utils.run(action)
```

In *utils.py* dinamically load config.txt according to *action* parameter using *base_path*:

```
def run(action):
    base_path = 'extras/BZ/'
    .
    .
    .
    filename = base_path + 'config2.txt'
    with open(filename) as f:
        result = json.load(f)
```

*IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\extras\BZ\config2.txt'*

It works when called directly in windows prompt inside root_folder, but it does't when called from script.rb. It needs to run on both cases.
Does anyone knows what is causing the error?

Comment: in the error message you get `\extras` ? you mean you get a leading backslash? Print `filename` and post the value please.

Comment: This is the filename print:
extras/BZ/config2.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
def run(action):
    base_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'extras/BZ/')
```

Answer (score 1):

your ruby script isn't started inside the root_folder, so your relative base path isn't correct. You can use `os.getcwd()` to fetch your current working directory. A relative path always starts from there.

In general it is better to always use absolute paths, when possible. For creating absolute pathes, it is good practice to use `os.path.join()` instead of just concatenating strings.

Comment: Hi, yes I found some saying to use os.getcwd() but it returns C:\Users\user\Documents
If I concatenate with os.path.realpath it will be:
C:\Users\user\Documents\\extras\BZ\config2.txt, missing the root_folder in the middle

Comment: @FelipeBarbosa well, so now you know, that you are not in your root_folder. so expand your cwd with your root_folder, or extend your base path, in order to reach the directory using a relative path.

Comment: I guess this is not possible, the name of the root_folder is unknown, it depends on the users PC, also is not possible to change script.rb.

Comment: Thanks for you input, the trick was to use os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), the solution was os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'extras/BZ/')

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if your run script.rb from its folder then ALL OF THE CODE gets run as if it were in that folder.
And so I think you should try setting base_path to './root_folder/extras/BZ/' just to check if that's the problem.